# change registered users 1=123

Tags: php, mysql

```
//connect to the server
mysql_connect("mysql", "root", "") or die ("cannot connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db ("db") or die ("Can not Connet to the database ");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users")or die(mysql_error());
$nrows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo $nrows;
```

the php code shows registered users.
now i have 2 registered users and it show 2 i need to change like this 1 registered user =123 for example if i have 2 registered users it must show 246 on website how can i do like this

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? Could please try to explain what you are trying to achieve in a bit more detail? Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply your result.

```
echo $nrows * 123;
```